# I have a youtube url using that how I can show video in my site

Tags: youtube

I have a youtube **url** using that how I can show video in my site.
for example : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXX
suppose this is my video link. I have saved this in my database.
I need to show this video in my site, for that what code I have to write.
(I am retriving that code in my html page but it is not showing the video using embed).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Click on **Share**, then on **Embed**. Take it from there.

Comment: This might work if the OP has a single entry. Let's assume there are a thousand entries, and the database is designed that some user can insert a link from YouTube. In that case he got to do it on the fly. But still, this was my first thought too. :)

Comment: That was what the OP said, "I have a Youtube url". You're right that this will not work if you want to do it automatically, but then, neither do the other answers! Let's see how the OP responds.

Comment: You're right on this one. :) Still the easiest way to go - I don't want to devalue your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can have iFrame and load the video in it.

```
<iframe width="500" height="500"
src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXX">
</iframe>
```

or you can embed the video like

```
<embed
width="500" height="500"
src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXX"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

embed using iframe

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="/* YOUR YOUTUBE URL*/" frameborder="0" 
    ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you have to modify the string and get it into this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXX" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So split off everything after *=* and paste it into this source using PHP or any other language. You can also do this with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I always do the following which works great for me.
Because youtube can have several urls like 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXX' or 'http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXXXX' i do parse_url and parse_str to get the v id.

```
<?php $youtube_url =  'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXX';
parse_str(parse_url($youtube_url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $youtube); ?>

<object width="400" height="224">
<param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/<?= $youtube['v'] ?>"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/<?= $youtube['v'] ?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="224" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```